# unrecognized selector sent to instance Error with Facebook SDK for Xcode 7

Tags: parse-platform, swift2, xcode7, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am using the recent facebook sdk and parse sdk for ios. When i try to run my app on the simulator i get the following error:

```
ParseStarterProject-Swift[2841:107652] -[PFUserAuthenticationController authenticationDelegateForAuthType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd0bbc34620
2015-09-30 00:56:33.960 ParseStarterProject-Swift[2841:107652] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFUserAuthenticationController authenticationDelegateForAuthType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd0bbc34620'
```

This error is when i call the facebook application in my appdelegate file.

```
 PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
```

The following is my stack trace.

```
First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001102cef65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011280fdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001102d758d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110224f7a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110224b28 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   ParseStarterProject-Swift           0x000000010f06fdf5 +[PFFacebookUtils _authenticationProvider] + 139
    6   ParseStarterProject-Swift           0x000000010f06fe4c +[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:] + 48
    7   ParseStarterProject-Swift           0x000000010ef42f50 _TFC25ParseStarterProject_Swift11AppDelegate11applicationfS0_FTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVSs10DictionaryCSo8NSObjectPSs9AnyObject____Sb + 2160
    8   ParseStarterProject-Swift           0x000000010ef43903 _TToFC25ParseStarterProject_Swift11AppDelegate11applicationfS0_FTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVSs10DictionaryCSo8NSObjectPSs9AnyObject____Sb + 179
    9   UIKit                               0x000000011138f4ca -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 272
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000111390670 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3415
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000111396e15 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1755
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000111393ff0 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    13  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000113ef37ac -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
    14  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000113ef3b1a -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001101fb0a1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001101f0fcc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001101f0483 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001101efe98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    19  UIKit                               0x000000011139398d -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000111398676 UIApplicationMain + 171
    21  ParseStarterProject-Swift           0x000000010ef449dd main + 109
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001133e492d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this error doing the following:

First I deployed the official version of Parse Server (instead of Rob's version). Open this link and click 'Deploy to Heroku', follow the steps. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example

After that I downloaded the Parse Frameworks (including Facebook framework) from the link below and replaced all current frameworks in my project with these frameworks downloaded. https://parse.com/downloads/ios/parse-library/latest

Other than that just follow the class steps (adding code to AppDelegate, Info.pslist e etc.

Any problems, let me know.